# Clarify tag [esp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is an [esp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esp) tag on Stack Overflow, which lacks any description. Most of the questions in this tag seem related to the ESP8266 WiFi board (which I expected when navigated to the tag), but some of them do not.

If my understanding of this tag is correct, I'd suggest renaming it to ESP8266 (so that there would be no questions about ESP x86 register) and adding a tag wiki.

Comment: I knew this tag wasn't about extra-sensory perception before I even opened it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan be careful, the government could be looking for you!

Comment: Maybe we can add it to that class of questions where we must guess what the OP wants?

Comment: @RadLexus: No, those you should retag as [tag:my-crystal-ball-is-cloudy-today]

Comment: The actions you're describing taking seem at least reasonable; however, where do the questions regarding the x86 register live then?

Comment: I don't think the x86 register needs its own tag. Tag with [tag:x86] and [tag:stack], or perhaps consider creating a [tag:stack-pointer] tag that could be used with any architecture. That is clearer and more elegant on a number of different levels. @makoto

Comment: @CodyGray: do we even need a `stack-pointer` tag?  There is already a `call-stack` tag.  Perhaps they should be synonyms.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize we had a [call-stack] tag. Maybe they should be made synonyms. Although it concerns me a bit that a stack pointer has uses beyond the call stack, primarily in the allocation of space on the stack for storing local variables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've retagged all of the questions which were about the ESP8266, as well as a couple which were typos for [eps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eps) (the file format).

None of the remaining questions are about the ESP8266 -- many of them date to before it existed. Some of them are about the x86 stack register, some are about [a type of IPSec packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec#Encapsulating_Security_Payload), some of them are about Email Service Providers, and some are about other things entirely. These questions will need to be retagged manually.

---

Update: I have finished clearing out the tag, primarily by retagging all of the remaining questions about IPSec to [ipsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipsec), if they weren't already -- there's no need for a separate tag.

Answer (score 12):

@CodyGray retagged a lot of the x86 stack-pointer questions to [stack-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-pointer).

I wrote [a tag-wiki for it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-pointer/info), with some generic stuff and links to details about the stack pointer on x86, ARM, AArch64, MIPS, PowerPC, and AVR to provide an interesting sample of different ways the stack pointer can work on different ISAs.

Oh, I forgot SPARC.  Its rotating register window makes the call-stack interesting. :P

Comment: I am still planning to finish retagging the rest of them, but I didn't want to do too many at a time, so as not to overwhelm people like me who work primarily off of the home page!

Comment: If you're looking to challenge people's assumptions in that tag wiki, you could reference Itanium's second stack (the "register backing store").  See e.g. [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050421-28/?p=35833) and [way more detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150729-00/?p=90801/).  (I've never worked with SPARC; does SPARC work similarly?)

Answer (score 5):

I added a brief tag wiki to provide at least some disambiguation hints for [esp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esp). Not 100% complete, but perhaps better than nothing.